# Java DecimalFormatter - different behavior between Locale DE and Locale US

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm seeing odd behavior when I use Java's DecimalFormatter with different Locales.  If the number is a double coming in with the value 1,255,000,000 (in the debugger, it shows as 1.255E9), I pass it to the DecimalFormatter with a Locale.

If the Locale is set to de|DE, it converts the number to 1.255E13.

If the Locale is set to en|US, it converts the number (correctly) to 1.255E9.

Why is the German Locale doing it wrong?

Here's my code...

```
// number comes from JSP
// usually in form of "1.255E9"
String text = request.parameter("number");
NumberFormat numFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(formatLocale); 
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormatter)numFormatter;
formatter.applyPattern("#,###");
return formatter.parse(text.trim()).doubleValue();
```

** EDIT FOR MORE CLARITY **

The string getting passed to the server-side code is exactly as I outlined it above, "1.255E9".  On the JSP page, I'm simply doing HTML like

```
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="<%=price%>">
```

Comment: Can you please post a small reproducible example?

Comment: What `DecimalFormatter` method are you using?  I think I would have expected a `ParseException`, or "1.255", depending on the method, because in DE the "," is a decimal point, and you don't expect two decimal points in a number.

(For me, `NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("DE")).parse("1,255,000,000")` returns `1.255`, as expected since `',' == NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("DE")).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()`.)

Answer (score 2):

Some European countries (including Germany) use `,` as decimal separator and `.` as grouping separator (thousand separator). So, the same number `12345.678` can have different representation:

```
12,345.678 (US)
12.345,678 (Germany)
```

You can check the decimal separator and grouping separator like this:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for(Locale l : locales) {
  DecimalFormatSymbols s = ((DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(l))
    .getDecimalFormatSymbols();
  System.out.printf("%s:\t%s\t%s\n",
    l.getDisplayCountry(),
    s.getGroupingSeparator(),
    s.getDecimalSeparator());
}
```

Due to this reason, the string `1,255,000,000` is parsed to `1255000000` in US locale, and to `1.255` in DE(Germany) locale.

Comment: How does this explain the `1.255E13` that OP is noticing?

Comment: It's not clear the `1.255E13` result can be reproduced. Something else is going on that the OP hasn't mentioned.

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity.  The String getting parsed is "1.255E9".

Comment: So, 1255E9 should result in 1.255e12, but not ...e13